# Can you put an array into a JLabel (java )

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to make/add functions to a hang-man game and I stumbled upon the following problems when trying to display the letters that are correctly guessed.

The part of the code that I am implying on is meant to work as follows:

When a letter is correctly guessed `index` is supposed to get the index the following letter was placed in, in the char array: `randomWord`.

What I want to happen after that is for the array: `displayWord` to be set on the label: `rättord` and then for every letter that is correctly guessed the index that contains that letter gets visible.

How do I add the array: `displayWord` to the `JLabel`: `rättord`?
I want to do this with the purpose of only revealing one letter a time in the array.

The goal is to make every letter that is correctly  guessed appear in the `JLabel rättord`,  any other methods of displaying correctly guessed words are welcome.

(the current code )

The code:

```
package hangmann;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class HangMan extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
private int error;
JButton button;
JTextField field;
JFrame frame;
JLabel rättord;

HangMan(JButton button, JTextField field, JFrame frame, JLabel rättord) {
    this.button = button;
    this.field = field;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.rättord = rättord;
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

static String [] ord = {"london", "stockholm", "berlin", "rome", "" }; 
static Random r = new Random();
static int randomNumber=r.nextInt(ord.length);
static String d = ord[randomNumber];

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    String guessedWord = field.getText();
    if (source.equals(button)) {
        if (!d.contains(guessedWord)) {
            error++;
            frame.repaint();
            rättord.setText(d);
        }
        if (d.contains(guessedWord)) {
            char [] randomWord = d.toCharArray();   
            char CharGuessedWord = guessedWord.charAt(0);
            
            int index = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++ ) {
                if(randomWord[i] == CharGuessedWord) {
                    index = 1+ i;}
                else {
                    i = i+ 1 ; 
                }
            }

            char [] displayWord = d.toCharArray();

            rättord.setText(Integer.toString(index));
        }
        field.setText("");
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (error == 1)
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
    if (error == 2) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
    }
    if (error == 3) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
    }
    if (error == 4) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
    }
    if (error == 5) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
    }
    if (error == 6) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
    }
    if (error == 7) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
    }
    if (error == 8) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
    }
    if (error == 9) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);
    }
    if (error == 9) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);
    }
    if (error == 10) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 170, 400, 150);
    }
    if (error == 11) {
        g.drawLine(10, 270, 500, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 270);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 350, 30);
        g.drawLine(250, 30, 200, 75);
        g.drawLine(350, 30, 350,100);
        g.drawOval(330, 100, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(350, 140, 350,200);
        g.drawLine(350, 200,390, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 200, 310, 240);
        g.drawLine(350, 170, 400, 150);
        g.drawLine(350, 170, 300, 150);
  }        
    if(error > 11) {
        g.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 26));
        g.drawString("GAME OVER", 225, 150);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HangMan");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JLabel rubrikOrd = new JLabel("rätt gissade ord");
    rubrikOrd.setOpaque(false);
    rubrikOrd.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rubrikOrd.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);

    JLabel rättord = new JLabel();
    rättord.setOpaque(true);
    rättord.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rättord.setBounds(10, 35, 100, 20);

    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.setVisible(true);

    JButton b = new JButton("ok");
    b.setBounds(370, 300, 100, 30);
    frame.add(b);
    field.setSize(300, 30);
    field.setLocation(60, 300);
    field.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.add(rättord);
    frame.add(rubrikOrd);

    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);

    HangMan object = new HangMan(b, field, frame, rättord);
    b.addActionListener(object);
    field.addActionListener(object);
    frame.add(object);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
}
```

The part I'm referring to:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    
    String guessedWord = field.getText();
    
    if (source.equals(button)) {
        if (!d.contains(guessedWord)) {
            error++;
            frame.repaint();
            rättord.setText(d);
        }
        if (d.contains(guessedWord)) {
            char [] randomWord = d.toCharArray();   
            char CharGuessedWord = guessedWord.charAt(0);
            
            int index = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++ ) {
                if(randomWord[i] == CharGuessedWord) {
                    index = 1+ i;}
                else {
                    i = i+ 1 ; 
                }
            }
            char [] displayWord = d.toCharArray();

            rättord.setText(Integer.toString(index));
        }
        field.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a `StringBuilder` instead of an array. You can use the toString() method of the StringBuilder to get the text to display in the label.

Comment: i am trying to do it right now, and i think all the logic makes sense. However i am having an issue where after ive added the index and charGuessedWord: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 0, length 0 shows upp.

Comment: Well, the exception method says it all. The StringbBuilder is empty. You can't index an empty StringBuilder. Do you basic debugging to determine why it is empty.

Comment: Well, the exception method says it all. The StringbBuilder is empty. You can't index an empty StringBuilder. Why are you trying to access the text? You should just be "appending" a character each time a valid guess is made.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment, but isnt it possible for you to use a char array with same size as the randomWord, but all initialized to maybe an * or _, and on correct guess, replace the index with the char, then you can use a StringBuilder as mentioned by @camickr or you can use some custom toString() or other custom method to return the whole string representation of array elements and setText() for your label